# How do you make a checkerboard pattern?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <style>
        html {
            background-color: orange;
        }
        div.row span.box {
            height: 50px;
            width: 50px;
            background-color: gray;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        div.row {
            height: 50px;
            width: 400px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        if (document.readyState == 'loading') {
          document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready)
        } else {
          ready()
        }
        
        function ready() {
            var boxs = document.getElementsByClassName('box')
            for (var i = 0; i < boxs.length; i++) {
                var stop = false
                if (i % 8 == 0 && i !== 0) {
                    boxs[i].style.backgroundColor = boxs[i-1].style.backgroundColor
                    for (var j = 1; j < boxs[i].parentElement.getElementsByTagName('span').length; j++) {
                        boxs[i].parentElement.getElementsByTagName('span')[j - 1].style.backgroundColor == 'white' ? boxs[i].parentElement.getElementsByTagName('span')[j].style.backgroundColor = 'black' : boxs[i].parentElement.getElementsByTagName('span')[j].style.backgroundColor = 'white'
                    }
                    stop = true
                }
                if (stop == false) {
                    if (i % 2 == 0) {
                        boxs[i].style.backgroundColor = 'black'
                    } else {
                        boxs[i].style.backgroundColor = 'white'
                    }
                }
            }
           }
    </script>
  </head>

  <header>
    <div>
        <div class="row" id="row1">
            <span class="box s1"></span
            ><span class="box s2"></span
            ><span class="box s3"></span
            ><span class="box s4"></span
            ><span class="box s5"></span
            ><span class="box s6"></span
            ><span class="box s7"></span
            ><span class="box s8"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="row2">
            <span class="box s1"></span
            ><span class="box s2"></span
            ><span class="box s3"></span
            ><span class="box s4"></span
            ><span class="box s5"></span
            ><span class="box s6"></span
            ><span class="box s7"></span
            ><span class="box s8"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="row3">
            <span class="box s1"></span
            ><span class="box s2"></span
            ><span class="box s3"></span
            ><span class="box s4"></span
            ><span class="box s5"></span
            ><span class="box s6"></span
            ><span class="box s7"></span
            ><span class="box s8"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="row4">
            <span class="box s1"></span
            ><span class="box s2"></span
            ><span class="box s3"></span
            ><span class="box s4"></span
            ><span class="box s5"></span
            ><span class="box s6"></span
            ><span class="box s7"></span
            ><span class="box s8"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="row5">
            <span class="box s1"></span
            ><span class="box s2"></span
            ><span class="box s3"></span
            ><span class="box s4"></span
            ><span class="box s5"></span
            ><span class="box s6"></span
            ><span class="box s7"></span
            ><span class="box s8"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="row6">
            <span class="box s1"></span
            ><span class="box s2"></span
            ><span class="box s3"></span
            ><span class="box s4"></span
            ><span class="box s5"></span
            ><span class="box s6"></span
            ><span class="box s7"></span
            ><span class="box s8"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="row7">
            <span class="box s1"></span
            ><span class="box s2"></span
            ><span class="box s3"></span
            ><span class="box s4"></span
            ><span class="box s5"></span
            ><span class="box s6"></span
            ><span class="box s7"></span
            ><span class="box s8"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="row8">
            <span class="box s1"></span
            ><span class="box s2"></span
            ><span class="box s3"></span
            ><span class="box s4"></span
            ><span class="box s5"></span
            ><span class="box s6"></span
            ><span class="box s7"></span
            ><span class="box s8"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <body>

  </body>

  <footer>

  </footer>
</html>
```

Hello, my problem here, is that I am trying to make a chessboard/checkerboard pattern.

When I try, it looks more like strips of black and white (the colors I am using). I figured out that it is because of me trying to get the index and modulo it by two (index % 2) and that is making the problem. So I tried some stuff with index modulo eight, (index % 8) and that didn't help either.

Comment: Use of HTML body, header, footer tags is incorrect.

Comment: That is not the problem

Comment: I recommend removing code that does not work from the question because you will get much more variety in answers if you just say: "How to make checker-board in HTML?"

Comment: Do you need to put checkers in the cells?

Answer (score 1):

```css
:root {
  --size: 1.5rem;
  --color: black;
}

table.board {
  border: 2px solid var(--color);
  border-collapse:collapse;
}

table.board td {
  height: var(--size);
  width: var(--size);
  text-align: center;
}

table.board tr {
  height: var(--size);
}

table.board tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(odd),
table.board tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(even) {
  background: var(--color);
}
```

```html
<table class="board">
  <tr>
    <td>⚪️</td>
    <td>⚫️</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```